# $\text{Hom}_{k}(U \oplus V,W) \cong \text{Hom}_{k}(U,W) \oplus \text{Hom}_{k}(V,W)$

Tags: ring-theory, modules, representation-theory

Let $U,V$ and $W$ be $kG$-modules. Then, as $kG$-modules, show the following are isomorphic.

$$\text{Hom}_{k}(U \oplus V,W) \cong \text{Hom}_{k}(U,W) \oplus \text{Hom}_{k}(U,W),$$

$$\text{Hom}_{k}(U,V \oplus W) \cong \text{Hom}_{k}(U,V) \oplus \text{Hom}_{k}(U,W).$$

I'm really struggling with this proof. I've been able to verify that the dimensions are the same, but I'm not sure that's enough as these aren't vector spaces. Any hints?

Comment: In any category having them, it's a general theorem of coproducts that $\hom(A \amalg B, C) \cong \hom(A, C) \times \hom(B, C)$, and it's a general theorem of products that $\hom(A, B \times C) \cong \hom(A,B) \times \hom(A, C)$.

Comment: Try writing up explicitly isomorphisms between them as vector spaces first.

Comment: @Hurkyl But these (co)products are taken in a different category than the morphisms, so there is technically still something to check.

Comment: @Hurkyl sorry, i don't know any category theory..

Comment: There is a clear isomorphism of $k$ modules. Now show that that isomorphism commutes with the $G$ action.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Does the forgetful functor $Rep(G) \to Vec_k$ not preserve (co)products?

Comment: @leibnewtz Sure, but that is an extra step. And even then, we have the wrong morphisms to start with.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*: If $\eta\in \mathrm{Hom}(U\oplus V, W)$, then $\eta(u,v) = \eta(u,0) + \eta(0,v)$.

What can we now define using $\eta(u,0)$ and $\eta(0,v)$?